# Is there a "smooth" version of \Letter?

Tags: symbols, unicode, characters

From the `ifsym` package I have `\Letter`, which gives

[image]

Is there a smooth version of this? I want something like the Unicode ✉, or

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the fontawesome5 package

Comment: If you use an unicode engine like lualatex, you could use whatever font has `✉`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz This is very useful! However, from the documentation, I only seem to get the version on the right (without the two bottom lines).

Comment: The `marvosym` package also has this glyph. Maybe it renders better?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I have tried it, but I got a similar result.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling your document? I cannot reproduce this. Consider providing an MWE and tell us which compilation mechanism and viewer you use.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Just using Overleaf. What do you get, a smooth version of `\Letter`?

Comment: I just use `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{marvosym} \begin{document} \Letter \end{document}` and get a nicely scalable glyph. With `\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}` I get indeed a rasterized glyph (but it has a higher definition as the one you show).

Comment: Have you visited the overleaf preview or the generated PDF? In the generated PDF I see a “smooth” letter symbol. You can use `\Huge`, `\huge`, `\Large`, … and `\fontsize{…}{…}` to scale it.

Comment: I have seen the PDF version, not the preview. I can't upload a MWE right now, but I am using [this bioRxiv Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws).

Comment: Well, this document class loads `\RequirePackage[misc]{ifsym}`. This means, that if you try to load another package that defines `\Letter`, you will get an error that this command is already defined. You should never ignore such errors. Apart from that, if you had provided a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in the first place, it would have been much easier to come up with a solution.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes I know what a MWE is, but as I explained I could not upload it. Besides, your suggestion is simply wrong, I do not get that error because I'm not loading another package, you assumed this. If you had tried running the template I shared, on Overleaf, you'd easily realise that the issue persists independently of what you wrote. Simply open the template on Overleaf, compile the PDF, download it, open it on Adobe Acrobat Reader and zoom in on the \Letter character (which, btw, is already on the template, so you do not need to change anything). Hope this is a good enough MWE.

Comment: I do not assume anything. I just clicked the link you provided and opened the template and I already get an error. Note that even if you get a PDF, if you additionally get an error (shown in Overleaf by a [small red tag with a number over the document icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPVUq.png)), the output is typically not right. See my answer for a full explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant glyph provided by the `ifsym` package is not fully scalable, but you can use the `marvosym` package that provides a scalable glyph via the same commant, that is `\Letter`.

However, if I read your comments correctly, you seem to use the `zHenriquesLab-StyleBioRxiv` document class as provided by some [Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/henriqueslab-biorxiv-template/nyprsybwffws). Having looked into the code of this document class, one will find that this document class loads the `ifsym` package.

The problem now is, that the `marvosym` package will issue an error because the commands `\Letter` and `\Cross` are already defined by the `ifsym` package. So, you cannot simply load the `marvosym` package, because the document class already loads the `ifsym` package. The result will be that you still get the glyph from the `ifsym` package and at least two errors.

A solution could be to undefine the relevant commands before loading the `marvosym` package.

```
\documentclass{zHenriquesLab-StyleBioRxiv}
\let\Letter\undefined 
\let\Cross\undefined 
\usepackage{marvosym}

\leadauthor{Doe} 
\title{Some Title}
\author[1,\Letter]{John Doe}
\affil[1]{Some Affiliation}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

This should result in the following output with a fully scalable envelope glyph:

[image]

But there is another problem: If I open the above linked Overleaf template just like this and compile, I already get an error which states `Package cleveref Error: cleveref must be loaded after hyperref!.`. Note that in Overleaf, if there is a tiny red badge over the document icon with a number in it, this means that there is at least one error in the code and the resulting PDF (if any) should be handled with utmost caution:

[image]

So, there is obviously already a problem in the code of the template which can be solved by commenting out the first occurance of `\RequirePackage{cleveref}` in the file `zHenriquesLab-StyleBioRxiv.cls` (this line can be found twice in the code, which in itself cannot be said to be good practice). So, I am not sure whether you should really use this template just like this in the first place.

Never ignore errors even if you get an PDF as output. In most cases the output will be wrong!

Comment: +1 for your last paragraph :)